# Google Analytics Data API in C# code without using ViewId

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, google-analytics-4

I have old method (Universal analytic) of
**GetReportsResponse response = service.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();**

I am sending following things in Request
1)ViewId = "",
2)DateRanges ,
3)Metrics = sessions,
4)Dimensions = browser,

How Can I retrieve GA4 Real time user data by using property Id?... I don't have View Id in Google Analytic 4.
Please help me in c# code with step by step process.